# clearml-serving-triton | 2022-06-18 16:21:19,790 - clearml.Task - INFO - No repository found, storing script code instead

Tags: docker, clearml

i found this error when running this command "docker-compose --env-file example.env -f docker-compose-triton.yml up".
Actually, when i run this command for the first time, it worked. And then when I try to change to my friend's workspace it suddenly give this error when I run the command again.
I've tried changing example.env file configuration and reinstall the docker, still not worked.
Can anyone help? or have the solution? Thank You :)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp8XK.png
[Error details on the image]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a team members of ClearML

> And then when I try to change to my friend's workspace it suddenly give this error when I run the command again

It seems Triton failed to load your actual TF model, the main reason for that is drivers installed on the Host machine are not supported by the nvidia cuda inside the container (yes these things happen).

You can see here the Triton container is built on [nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.04-py3](https://github.com/allegroai/clearml-serving/blob/6005e238cac6f7fa7406d7276a5662791ccc6c55/clearml_serving/engines/triton/Dockerfile#L2), which requires [driver version 510 or up](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/support-matrix/index.html)